# Display of no. of items in cart on navbar shows 0 on refresh

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

So in my angular application. I am trying to add movies to a cart. I am able to add them to the cart, and the correct no. of movies in the cart are reflected back on the navbar, but on refresh, it turns to 0.

HTML of displaying count

```html
      <li *ngIf="signedIn" class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="active">
        <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/cart',authService.decodedToken.nameid]">Cart <span class="badge badge-dark">{{cartItemCount}}</span></a>
      </li>
```

My shared service through which I am updating-

```js
export class SharedcartService {

  private currentCartCount = new BehaviorSubject(0);
  currentMessage = this.currentCartCount.asObservable();

  constructor() {
   }

  addMovieToCart(movie: any) {
    sessionStorage.setItem('movie', JSON.stringify(movie));
  }
  getMovieFromCart() {
    return JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('movie'));
  }
  removeAllMovieFromCart() {
    return sessionStorage.removeItem('movie');
  }

  updateCartCount(count: number) {
    this.currentCartCount.next(count);
  }
}
```

My cart.ts file

```html
export class CartComponent implements OnInit {
  user: User;
  defaultQuantity: number = 1;
  movieAddedTocart: any;
  allTotal: number;
  constructor(private http:HttpClient, private userService: UserService,private sharedService: SharedcartService,
    private alertify: AlertifyService,private route: ActivatedRoute ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.data.subscribe(data=>{
      this.user=data['user'];
    });
    this.movieAddedTocart=this.sharedService.getMovieFromCart();
    for (let i in this.movieAddedTocart) {
      this.movieAddedTocart[i].Quantity = 1;
    }
    this.sharedService.removeAllMovieFromCart();
    this.sharedService.addMovieToCart(this.movieAddedTocart);
    this.calculteAllTotal(this.movieAddedTocart);
  }

  onRemoveQuantity(movie: any)
  {
    this.movieAddedTocart=this.sharedService.getMovieFromCart();
    this.movieAddedTocart.find(p=>p.aMovieId == movie.aMovieId).Quantity = movie.Quantity-1;
    this.sharedService.removeAllMovieFromCart();
    this.sharedService.addMovieToCart(this.movieAddedTocart);
    this.calculteAllTotal(this.movieAddedTocart);
  }

  calculteAllTotal(allItems:any)
  {
    let total = 0;
    for (let i in allItems) {
      total= total+(allItems[i].Quantity *allItems[i].aPrice);
   }
   this.allTotal=total;
  }

  

}
```

[image: Navbar when i refresh]

Comment: Is it on refresh on the same tab or opening a new tab / window or even closing the browser?

Comment: I'm not familiar with angular, but is `new BehaviourSubject(0)` setting `currentCartCount` to `0` on load?

Comment: can you verify the state of your session storage in each step ? just to make sure the data you saved is in there or not ?

Comment: The data saved is there in the storage, as i am able to get the actual movies in the cart and they are there even after refresh.

Comment: yazantahhan, this is happening with opening a new tab and closing the browser too.

Comment: Can you make snippet here that reproduce the problem? here: http://stackblitz.com/

Answer (score 0):

May be Is it because ngOnInit it's executing  `this.sharedService.removeAllMovieFromCart()`  which removes all movies from cart